# Trying to make sense of [object HTMLCollection] From JavaScript .innerHTML Right Function?

Tags: javascript, html, object, collections

I'm a newcomer to JavaScript. I'm trying to get what I thought would be a simple "onchange" event to work with an input form element and have a JavaScript function write back the value of the input using .innerHTML.

Here is what my output looks like:

First Name *

Hello [object HTMLCollection]

How do I deal with a variable returning the message of "[object HTMLcollection]" Please be explicitIn answering, because as I said, I'm a newcomer to javascript.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>onchange event Testing input text</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function write_firstname()
{
var fnid = document.getElementById("fnm");
var fn = document.getElementsByName("first_name");

fnid.innerHTML = "Hello " + fn;
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<!---->
<label for="first">First Name *</label>
<br />
<div class="form_indent">

    <input id="first" type="text" name="first_name" onChange="write_firstname();" autofocus>
    <p id="fnm"></p>
    <br />
</div>
<!----> 
<!---->
<div class="form_indent">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</div>
<!---->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I know it's probably something simple.  Someone please kick me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByName("first_name");` returns a collection of elements matching the selector, a [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Note the `s` in `getElements...` everytime you see that, there's a chance more than one element could match, and a nodeList is returned instead of a single DOM node.

A nodeList is an array-like object containing the elements, so you're trying to add an object to a string, and as that's not really possible, javascript runs `toString()` to turn the nodeList into a string, and the string representation is `[object HTMLCollection]`

What you could be doing instead is just passing the element to the function

```
<input id="first" type="text" name="first_name" onchange="write_firstname(this);" autofocus>
```

and then do

```
function write_firstname(elem) {
    var fnid = document.getElementById("fnm");

    fnid.innerHTML = "Hello " + elem.value;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/28T2S/)